# How to use Calendar, Messaging, Photos and other such icons in new Windows 8 menu?

Tags: windows-8

How to use Calendar, Messaging, Photos and other such icons in new Windows 8 menu? They are all cause empty colored screens for me, some ones with waiting icon. But waiting appears endless.

**UPDATE**

Oh people, you need screenshots EVEN HERE!

Okay you get it.

This is screenshot of "Calendar":

[image]

(just white screen)

And this is screenshot of "Sports":

[image]

(just blue screen with a pot and "waiting icon" you were asking about)

Any more details required? May be post other screenshots too to clarify the problem? :D

Comment: Could you provide a screenshot, specially of the "waiting" icons?

Comment: Please provide more information about the problem.  A screenshot of the problem would help.  Verify you are NOT using the default `Administrator` account built into Windows.

Comment: Run the app troubleshooter and look if it can fix some issues: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkId=271185